# Apache Multiply Sites again

Tags: apache, apache2, lamp, virtualhost

OK. I have LAMP server on my local development machine. I need to develop few sites on it. So, I've created two files (configs of my sites) in $APACHE/sites-available and made symlinks for them for /sites-enabled. After that I've started sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart. No errors or warnings. When I try mysite.dev it gives it, and when foobar.dev - it gives mysite.dev!

So, apache gives one site for all virtual hosts. How to fix it?

http://pastebin.com/qjcx6RS3 (first site)
http://pastebin.com/FdVStJm8 (second site)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set [`NameVirtualHost`-directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) like this in your httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Example with two vhosts (like in your case):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

... it would of course also be possible to [include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/de/mod/core.html#include) the vhosts from seperate files into the httpd.conf.

Comment: Now it prints: " NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts"

Comment: Make sure that both your virtualhost files are included (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/de/mod/core.html#include) in httpd.conf ...and move the `ServerName` inside the `<VirtualHost>`

Comment: like on severfault mentioned it could also be possible that you have set `NameVirtualHost` two times in your configuration: http://serverfault.com/questions/1405/apache-2-startup-warning-namevirtualhost-80-has-no-virtualhosts